# If I buy a second-hand laptop from someone, who should be the owner of the installed Operating System / Windows 7 CD?

Tags: windows, laptop

If I buy a second-hand laptop from someone, who should be the owner of the installed Operating System / Windows 7 CD ?

Should the installed "Operating System / Windows 7 CD" stay with the Original Owner/Licensee Owner?

Or could it be included/pass-on to the buyer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer the **original license owner to yours**,Unless the license type is transferred to you from original owner ,You can't be owner of it!

According to [Microsoft faq](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=SOzfWvNZnr0) :

> Please look at the End User Software License Terms to find out which
>   type of license has been issued for the Microsoft software on the
>   computer system and check the provisions relating to transfer. To find
>   and read the End User Software License Terms, click Start on the
>   taskbar, click Help and Support, and do a search for eula.txt.
>
> Generally speaking, in the case of OEM or OEM System Builder software,
>   the license may not be transferred to a new or different PC. However,
>   the entire used PC, including the software media, manuals, and
>   Certificate of Authenticity, may be transferred to another end user
>   along with the software license rights.

And at transfer of license section :

> After an OEM software license has been installed on a PC, the license
>   may not be installed on or transferred to another PC. However, the
>   entire PC may be transferred to another end user along with the
>   software license rights. When transferring the PC to the new end user,
>   the software media, manuals (if applicable), and Certificate of
>   Authenticity label must be included. It is also advisable to include
>   the original purchase invoice or receipt. The original end user cannot
>   keep any copies of the software.

Comment: @ Vignesh4303 : "However, the entire used PC, including the software media, manuals, and Certificate of Authenticity, may be transferred to another end user along with the software license rights." Thanks for this one. The unit that I had bought is with OEM Operating System +plus the Recovery CD. Mind me also asking if I do need any documentation or legal steps that need to be taken, in order to finalize or legalize the transfer of ownership of the entire laptop (including all its softwares and OS installed)?

Comment: @MultiBoot see transfer of license under microsoft faq